# Application_BeginRequest() not getting fired while loading the url in http

Tags: c#, http, global-asax

The Application_BeginRequest() in Global.asax.cs seems to be hitting  fine while running the url locally and in testing servers, but doesnt seem to hit while loading the url with http in production server. I am able to see the logs inside the Application_BeginRequest() while I run the url with https, but not while running in http.

Comment: Does the application work fine with http URL?

Comment: Looks like your logging level in production not allowing this messages to be logged.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya yes it works fine, only thing is I wanted it to redirect to HTTPS.

Comment: @AlexeyRumyantsev if there is a logging level restriction, then when I run the url in https it would not have been logging right. It is not logging only when I run the url in http, it logs fine in https

Comment: @user3315089 yes it is strange, but information you provided is not enough even for suggestions.